# Apache Spark :Build dynamic date and time filter based on the UI inputs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

UI that allows user to select year, month, quarter, weekOfYear, dayOfMonth, First/Second Half of Year and many more with valid combinations.

However, out of these all options user can request as per their requirement.

Filter Condition: I need to filter any data for say, Year 2017 and Quater 1st and 2nd month and 3 day of all week.

Using [Apache Spark Sql Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) We can build static query behind the scene like :

```
dataset.select(dataset.col("SalesQty"))
        .filter(year(dataset.col("Date")).equalTo("2017").and(quarter(dataset.col("Date")).equalTo("1")).and(dayofmonth(dataset.col("Date")).equalTo("3")))
        .show();
```

But that's the static one.

My question is, how do we add more conditions with AND or OR expression? 
How do we build this filter dynamically? Is there any Builder/Helper class available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Basically in order to build filters dynamically what we need to do is Just Map the objects with your UI response...

```
//// Response from UI
//// The column on which we need apply filter column
static String filterColumn = "SalesAmt";

//// It is the column in which we will search this conditions
static String searchColumn = "Date";

static String years = "2017,2016,2015";
static String quarters = "2,3";
```

Now as you have this data with you... You can pass this to Apache Spark SQL's predefined functions, like

```
dataset.select(dataset.col("*"))
.filter(year(dataset.col("Date")).gt("2015"))
.and(quarter(dataset.col("Date")).equalTo("1"))
.and(dayofmonth(dataset.col("Date")).equalTo("3"))
.show();
```

This is static and will filter your data.

Dynamic :

Create function like filter builder, that will generate final filter by combining all the filters you applied

```
//// FilterBuilder
static Dataset<Row> filterBuilder(Dataset<Row> dataset, Column column) {
        return dataset.filter(conditionAdder(column));

}
```

In order to create final filter you may have to add conditions dynamically based on UI fields. So you need to create function for each UI fields that may be a part of your filter condition.

For example `year` from UI, it's Condition add function would be:

```
//// Validate Year and call Year Adder
if (!years.isEmpty() || years != null) {
        column = yearConditionAdder(column, years);
}
```

And you gonna going to add actual conditions in this step:

```
//// YearConditionsAdder
static Column yearConditionAdder(Column filteredColumn, String years) {
    //// Year List
    List<String> yearList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(years.split(",")));

    for (String year : yearList) {

        filteredColumn = filteredColumn.and(year(filteredColumn).equalTo(year));
        }

        return filteredColumn;
    }
```

Like vise you can build functions for all the fields and you need to add final filtered column to your first dataset object. :)